# Local changes not updating Atlas in Flexible Sync'd realm

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have a collection containing Group objects with the following schema:

```
class Group : BaseEntity(), RealmObject {
    class UserInfo : EmbeddedRealmObject {
        var userId: Id? = null
        var username: String? = null
        var userBalance: Double = 0.0
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    override var _id: Id = createId()
    var groupName: String? = null
    var users: RealmList<Id> = realmListOf()
    var userInfo: RealmList<UserInfo> = realmListOf()
}
```

Group.users and Group.usersInfo is mimicking a dictionary with userId as key and UserInfo containing nickname, balance, etc. as value. Apparently the Kotlin SDK doesn't support RealmDictionary nor querying on embedded objects according to [Kotlin RQL docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/sync/subscribe/), that's why the schema is a little messy. My Sync subscription for the Groups collection is:

```
val config =
        SyncConfiguration.Builder(realmUser, setOf(Group::class, Group.UserInfo::class))
        .initialSubscriptions(rerunOnOpen = true) { realm ->
            add(realm.query<Group>("$0 IN users", userId))
        }
        .name("groupRealm")
        .build()

val realm: Realm by lazy { Realm.open(config) }
```

where the subscription query

```
add(realm.query<Group>("$0 IN users", userId))
```

is attempting to sync all Group objects that a userId belongs to, basically, through the Group.users and Group.userInfo fields I described earlier.

All the read and write operations into the local realm are fine, but when I go into the collections in Atlas, I don't see the updates in the Group collection. Also, when I add `.waitForInitialRemoteData()` to the config, my code times out. I also get an `OtherSessionError: operation canceled (ProtocolErrorCode=201)` in the App Services logs, and an empty query when it should show the subscription query mentioned above. Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe the syntax for a RealmList is `var userInfo: RealmList<UserInfo> = RealmList()`

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using the Realm Kotlin SDK. I think RealmList() is for Java SDK

Comment: Looking at the docs [Kotlin Supported Types](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/schemas/supported-types/) I see RealmList. There's also an example of attaching a listener to a Realm List here [React to Changes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/react-to-changes/#register-a-realmlist-change-listener) and then the official [Realm Kotlin SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/kotlin/1.4.0/library-base/-realm%20-kotlin%20-s-d-k/io.realm.kotlin.types/-realm-list/index.html). Search for `RealmList<` here on SO for example use cases